# Interior of a set with respect to a subspace and the topological space

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to prove or disprove this statement: Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$; let $A$ be a subset of $Y$. Then the interior of $A$ in $Y$ equals $\text{Int}A\cap Y$.

My idea is,  since $\text{Int}A\subset A\subset Y$, $\text{Int}A\cap Y=\text{Int}A$. So this problem is actually asking us to prove the interior of $A$ in $Y$ is the same as the interior of $A$ in $X$, namely $\text{Int}A$.

My counterexample to the statement is: Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with standard topology and $Y=[0,1)\cup\{2\}$. Let $A=\{2\}$. Notice $A=Y\cap(\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2})$, which means $A=\{2\}$ is open in $Y$. Hence the interior of $A$ in $Y$ is $A$ itself. However, given $\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology is a Hausdorff space, we say $A$ is closed in $X$ and $\text{Int}A=\emptyset$. In this scenario, the interior of $A$ in $Y$ and the interior of $A$ in $X$ does not coincide, the statement does not hold.

Is my idea ok? Or is there any easier counterexample?

Comment: Please check the statement you are asking to be proved. The statement is trivial and doesn't correspond to the part of the text that follows.

Comment: @Emo I don't understand your comment. The OP was asked to *prove or disprove* that statement and he correctly rewrote it and disproved it. I suppose that in the same exercise, he proved the analogous statement for closures.

Comment: This works. Another counterexample would be $A = Y = [0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R} = X$.

Comment: @AnneBauval The statement asks to prove that when $A\subseteq Y$, then the interior of $A$ in $Y$ is $Int A\cap Y = Int A$ (where?). By that how the question was constructed in the beginning, I thought it was asked for the interior fo $A$ in $Y$. Then the case is trivial. If it is asked for $Int A$ in $X$, then the counterexample is correct, but the question asked should be formed more appropriate (as he has proposed).